# RegEx - Match Numbers of Variable Length

Tags: regex

I'm trying to parse a document that has reference numbers littered throughout it.

> Text text text {4:2} more incredible text {4:3} much later on
>   {222:115} and yet some more text.

The references will always be wrapped in brackets, and there will always be a colon between the two. I wrote an expression to find them.

```
{[0-9]:[0-9]}
```

However, this obviously fails the moment you come across a two or three digit number, and I'm having trouble figuring out what that should be. There won't ever be more than 3 digits {999:999} is the maximum size to deal with.

Anybody have an idea of a proper expression for handling this?

Answer (score 187, accepted):

```
{[0-9]+:[0-9]+}
```

try adding plus(es)

Answer (score 107):

What regex engine are you using? Most of them will support the following expression:

```
\{\d+:\d+\}
```

The `\d` is actually shorthand for `[0-9]`, but the important part is the addition of `+` which means "one or more".

Answer (score 41):

Try this:

```
{[0-9]{1,3}:[0-9]{1,3}}
```

The `{1,3}` means "match between 1 and 3 of the preceding characters".

Answer (score 11):

You can specify how many times you want the previous item to match by using `{min,max}`.

```
{[0-9]{1,3}:[0-9]{1,3}}
```

Also, you can use `\d` for digits instead of `[0-9]` for most regex flavors:

```
{\d{1,3}:\d{1,3}}
```

You may also want to consider escaping the outer `{` and `}`, just to make it clear that they are not part of a repetition definition.

Comment: No please don't do it with most regex flavors, unless you love non-european digits: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm