# SQL Server - Like/Pattern Matching

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I'm trying to implement a check constraint on a key field. The key field is composed of a 3 character prefix, and then appended with numeric characters (which can be provided manually, but the default is to get an integer value from a sequence, which is then cast as nvarchar). The key field is defined as nvarhcar(9).

I'm doing this for multiple tables, but here is a specific example below to demonstrate:
Table name: Company
Key field: IDCompany
Key field prefix: CMP

Examples of valid keys -

```
CMP1
CMP01
CMP10000
CMP999999
```

Examples of invalid keys -

```
CMPdog1
steve
1CMP1
1
999999999
```

The check constraint I came up with was:

```
IDCompany LIKE 'CMP%[0-9]'
```

However, this is beaten by CMPdog1 etc.

What should I be using as a check constraint to enforce an unknown number of numeric characters?

I could do the following:

```
IDCompany LIKE 'CMP[0-9]' OR IDCompany LIKE 'CMP[0-9][0-9]' OR .... through to 6 characters
```

But, this seems like a clunky way of doing it, is there something smarter?

EDIT 2: This actually doesn't work, it does not exclude negative numbers:

```
EDIT 1:
This solution ended up working for me:

IDCompany nvarchar(9) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DEF_Company_IDCompany DEFAULT 'CMP' + CAST((NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.sq_Company) AS nvarchar) CONSTRAINT CHK_Company_IDCompany CHECK (IDCompany LIKE 'CMP%[0-9]' AND ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(IDCompany,4,LEN(IDCompany)-3))=1)
```

EDIT 3: Solution -
As proposed in Szymon's post below.

Thanks all!

Comment: Which database do you use?

Comment: So, having just asked this, I found something in regex that may help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407099/regex-match-numbers-of-variable-length

I will try this and report back.

Comment: This is SQL Server 2012

Comment: The '+' operator does not seem to work in SQL Server.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like that:

```
where LEFT(IDCompany, 3) = 'CMP'
    and isnumeric(RIGHT(IDCompany, len(IDCompany) - 3)) = 1
    and IDCompany not like '%[.,-]%'
```

The first part checks that it starts with CMP

The next part is to make sure that the rest is numeric but excluding negative and decimal numbers.

Comment: This similar to what I came up with based on shree.pat18's comment below, but your's looks like it has safeguards against some of the problems associated with ISNUMERIC.

Comment: I hope all of them but feel free to tweak that to your needs.

Comment: You might well be right, I based my comment on all of 20 seconds worth of testing, so i didn't want to over commit :-)

This seems to defeat almost all invalid cases that I could come up with, so thanks. This is my chosen solution.

Comment: You should go ahead and mark it as the answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, I would reconsider the design of your table and create 3 columns:

- **prefix**, CHAR(3), with a default as 'CMP' and a constraint to allow only 'CMP' combination
- **id**, INTEGER
- **companyid**, NVARCHAR(9), a computed, persisted column as sum of the first 2 columns. Most probably with an index on.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, SQL Server doesn't suppport regular expressions.

So there is only 2 ways to solve your problem:

1. Use CLR function for using regular expression. You may find more information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx)
2. Or whrite long `WHERE` clause like you suggested:

   IDCompany LIKE 'CMP[0-9]' OR IDCompany LIKE 'CMP[0-9][0-9]' OR ....

Comment: Thanks for the link on CLR and Regex, bookmarked that one!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
isnumeric(substring(IDCompany,4,len(IDCompany)))=1 and IDCompany not like '%[.,-]%'
```

How this works: The first three characters are fixed, so we only need to check from the 4th character onwards. So we get the required substring. Then, we use `isNumeric` to check if the substring is entirely numeric. Example [here](http://rextester.com/YTJKA20002)

EDIT: As pointed out in comments by Allan, we need an extra check to ensure that characters used in numeric strings like commas or dots are not part of the input string.

Comment: Although be aware of ISNUMERIC pitfalls where it returns true for something which isn't actually a number.