# how to convert string to int from a variable that holds chars & ints

Tags: java, android

i"m learning java and android SDK. for learning propers i built a calculator (not completed yet). 
in my code i used ImageView Tags to get the value of the button that the user clicked on:

```
ImageView button = (ImageView) view;        
String buttonTag = button.getTag().toString();
```

xml:

```
<ImageView
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:id="@+id/zero"
                android:layout_row="17"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:tag="0"
                android:onClick="calcPad" />
```

the ImageView Tags values are: "0" - "9", "plus"/"minus" etc..
so i converted it to chars to get the numbers and converted it back to int:

```
char[] charTag = buttonTag.toCharArray();
for (int z=0; z < charTag.length; z++) { 
        if (charTag[z] == '0') {number = 0;}
        if (charTag[z] == '1') {number = 1;}
        ...
        if (charTag[z] == '9') {number = 9;}
```

i have tried to use 'try' and 'catch' but the app crash. this what i have tried to do:

```
try{
     num = Integer.getInteger(buttonTag);

}  catch(NumberFormatException e) {
    Log.i("Exception", e.getMessage());
    switch(buttonTag) {
         case "Plus":
         .....
         default:
     }

}
```

what i need to add in order to 'handle' the exception? i tried to add in the catch a switch that get buttonTag value (that is string) but still the same problem.

the complete code (without the try/catch section):

```
 package com.example.idan.calculator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    double  var1 = 0;           //holds the first number
    double  var2 = 0;           //holds the second number
    int     decimalPoint = 0;   //indicate if the user clicked on the (.)
    String  var1string="";      //for processing
    String  var2string="";      //for processing
    double  var1Array[]={0,0};  // the return value of var1doublemaker
    double  var2Array[]={0,0};  // the return value of var2doublemaker
    boolean mathAction = false; // indicate if the user clicked on a mathematical button
    int     mathType = 0;       // help me identify between + - * /
    char    mathValue = 'x';    // for the display
    double  result = 0;         // final result

    public double[] var1doubleMaker (String buttonTag, int decimalPoint) {
        if (decimalPoint == 1) {                            //need to add dot to string
            var1string = var1string + "." + buttonTag;
            var1 = Double.valueOf(var1string);
            decimalPoint = 0;                               // set back to 0
            var1Array[0] = var1;
            var1Array[1] = decimalPoint;
        } else {
            var1string = var1string + buttonTag;            // add the last number
            var1 = Double.valueOf(var1string);
            var1Array[0] = var1;
            var1Array[1] = decimalPoint;
        }
        return(var1Array);


    }
    public double[] var2doubleMaker (String buttonTag, int decimalPoint) {
        if (decimalPoint == 1) {
            var2string = var2string + "." + buttonTag;
            var2 = Double.valueOf(var2string);
            decimalPoint = 0;
            var2Array[0] = var2;
            var2Array[1] = decimalPoint;
        } else {
            var2string = var2string + buttonTag;
            var2 = Double.valueOf(var2string);
            var2Array[0] = var2;
            var2Array[1] = decimalPoint;
        }
        return(var2Array);


    }


    public void calcPad(View view) throws NumberFormatException{

        //check which button the user clicked on-
        //  first: get the ImageView by id
        ImageView button = (ImageView) view;                  // where the user clicked on
        String buttonTag = button.getTag().toString();       // hold the tag as string for the switch
        char[] charTag = buttonTag.toCharArray();
        int number = 111;                                       // 111 - just for initialization
        int num = 111;
/*
        try{
             num = Integer.getInteger(buttonTag);

        }  catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            Log.i("Exception", e.getMessage());

        }
        */
        Log.i("info - num value:", String.valueOf(num));
        //Log.i("info char", String.valueOf(charTag[0]));

        char numberToResolve = charTag[0];
        switch (numberToResolve)  {
            case '0':
                number = 0;
                break;
            case '1':
                number = 1;
                break;
            case '2':
                number = 2;
                break;
            case '3':
                number = 3;
                break;
            case '4':
                number = 4;
                break;
            case '5':
                number = 5;
                break;
            case '6':
                number = 6;
                break;
            case '7':
                number = 7;
                break;
            case '8':
                number = 8;
                break;
            case '9':
                number = 9;
                break;
            default:
                    Log.i("error", "cant resolve number from charTag[]");
        }


        //Log.i("info number value", String.valueOf(number));

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.calcDisplay);  // create an object to print the button that the user clicked

        Log.i("info", buttonTag);

        // math
        if (buttonTag.length() > 1) {
            switch(buttonTag) {
                case "divid":
                    mathValue = '/';
                    mathAction = true;
                    mathType = 4;
                    break;
                case "multi":
                    mathValue = '*';
                    mathAction = true;
                    mathType = 3;
                    break;
                case "Plus":
                    mathValue = '+';
                    mathAction = true;
                    mathType = 1;
                    break;
                case "minus":
                    mathValue = '-';
                    mathAction = true;
                    mathType = 2;
                    break;
                case "dot":
                    decimalPoint = 1;
                case "equal":
                    if (mathType == 1) {
                        result = var1 + var2;
                    } else if (mathType == 2) {
                        result = var1 - var2;
                    } else if (mathType == 3) {
                        result = var1 * var2;
                    } else if (mathType == 4) {
                        result = var1 / var2;
                    }
                    String display = Double.toString(result);
                    textView.setText(display);
                    break;
                case "cc":
                    var1 = 0;
                    var2 = 0;
                    mathAction = false;
                    decimalPoint = 0;
                    result = 0;
                    var1string="";      //for processing
                    var2string="";
                    display = Double.toString(result);
                    textView.setText(display);
                    break;
                default:
                    Log.i("error", "cant resolve math type from buttonTag");
            }
        }

        //Log.i("info decimalpoint", String.valueOf(decimalPoint));


        if (number >= 0 && number <= 9 ) {
            // user clicked on a number
            //call doubleMaker
            if (mathAction) {
                //working on var2
                double[] var2temp = var2doubleMaker(buttonTag,decimalPoint);

                Double dd= var2temp[1];
                decimalPoint =  dd.intValue();      // set decimalPoint back to 0

                // display var1 + math + var2
                String display = Double.toString(var1) + Character.toString(mathValue) + Double.toString(var2temp[0]);

                textView.setText(display);
            } else {
                // working on var1
                double[] var1temp = var1doubleMaker(buttonTag,decimalPoint);

                Double d= var1temp[1];
                decimalPoint =  d.intValue();
                String display = Double.toString(var1temp[0]);

                textView.setText(display);
            }


        }

        Log.i("info - var1:", Double.toString(var1));
        Log.i("info - var2:", Double.toString(var2));
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407099/regex-match-numbers-of-variable-length)

Comment: How about using Integer.parseInt(buttonTag) and catch NumberFormatException?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to pass your string into this : Integer.parseInt("string"). This method help you convert from string to int

```
 ImageView button = (ImageView) view;                
 String buttonTag = button.getTag().toString();
 int number = Integer.parseInt(buttonTag)
```

Comment: there are some word in that string. that way i cant to it. the values are both number "0"- "9" and words like "plus" "minus" .. etc..

Comment: You can use button for plus and minus...etc... I used to button to build a calculator, and then set background for it if you want it look like an image. Or if you still want to use getTag() from ImageView, you can use if else (if for words like plus, minus.. and else for all number with Integer.parseInt (number))