# Regex for numbers, but without "-"

Tags: regex

Need regex which is match positive and negative numbers, but false for string - "-".

My regex doesn't work:

```
^-?[0-9]$
```

This regex true for "-", but i need so that she is false.

```
-123123; //true
12321; //true
-; //false
asdasd; //false
```

Help me please.

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: ^-?\d+$ works for me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407099/regex-match-numbers-of-variable-length this doesn't works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need at least one digit, so

```
^-?\d+$
```

should do the trick

Or this may be better

```
 ^(0|-?[1-9]+\d*)$
```

The second expression is better as it prevents numbers from having numbers with lots of zeros prefixed (e.g. 00000001) and also -0

Comment: Could you please explain your second regex?  I don't see how it's better from the first one

Comment: @AleksAndreev the second regex requires that the number not start with a 0, unless the number is 0 itself.  "-0 is also invalid for it.