# Regular Expression date issue

Tags: regex

I have multiple strings I want to loop through and check if any match the below format (unix timestamp, space, d/m/Y)

> 1513592758 18/12/2017

I have been using https://regexr.com/ to test and the closest I have gotten is using the below

```
([0-9]) (0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d
```

but this still does not give me an exact match.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: A `+` after the first `[0-9]` should help.

Comment: Programming languages usually support date string to date object conversion, why not leverage that? What programming language are you using here?

Comment: Probably a dupe of [RegEx - Match Numbers of Variable Length
Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407099/regex-match-numbers-of-variable-length)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are soo close

```
([0-9]+) (0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[ /.-](0[1-9]|1[012])[ /.-](19|20)\d\d
```

The plus means: one or more of the preceding character (class)